# how can i do live preview?

Tags: jquery

I would like to have live preview functionality.
can anyone give me the code. I am using bootstrap for styling. I have tried to use keyup() for live preview I don't understand what's wrong with it.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="question">Question</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xxlarge" type="text" name="question" id="question" required="true" placeholder="write your question"><span class="preview"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is my jquery for live preview.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         /* <![CDATA[ */

        $('.input-xxlarge').keyup(function(){
            var input-xxlarge = $(this).val();
            $("preview").html(input-xxlarge);
            {return false;}
        });

    /* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: *"I don't understand what's wrong with it"* For one, there are no elements with the name `preview` in HTML. Maybe you meant to use an ID selector, `#preview`.

Comment: sorry for that I have edited that mistake. I am using preview as <span class="preview"></span> beside my textfield for live preview.

Comment: You have to fix the selector as well. And if you look at the console, you will see the error `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` or something similar. `-` is not valid as part of a variable name, use another character. To learn how to debug JavaScript code, have a look at http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

Comment: Thanks Felix the problem is in '-' i use simple variable name now its work. I would like to now how can i do live preview of form as in Stack overflow while asking question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you use `id` instead of `class`es for the job.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="question">Question</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="input-xxlarge" type="text" name="question" id="question"
        required="true" placeholder="write your question" /> <span class="preview"></span>

    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
$('.input-xxlarge').keyup(function () {
    var impt = $(this).val();
    $(".preview").html(impt);
});
```

work just fine. Here's a link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D7L3n/).

Comment: Thanks dream eater it is really good site.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't use "-" for variable name

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.input-xxlarge').keyup(function(){
            var inputxxlarge = $(this).val();
            $(".preview").html(inputxxlarge);
            {return false;}
        });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this that exactly you want i guess ??

http://jsfiddle.net/8ajQF/2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").keypress(function(){
     var sac = $(this).val();
    $("span").text(sac);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is not "live" when text is deleted from the textbox. I think "keydown" or "keyup" would be an appropriate event to target in this case.